# PL/SQL - How to Run different Select According to Table Field Value

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have the following situation within a PL/SLQ function.
Depending of existing table field value I might run a different select.
Specifically:
I can have multiple rows for a particular BILL CODE (PINGPONG) where I would only need to get the SYS_FIELD value.
This field has to be fetched only once according to following condition:
If fields prep_seq_num=0 and primary_ind=0 then just get this rows sys_field value straightaway and do not take care of other possible prep_seq_num and primary_ind values different from 0.
If that rows is not existing, fetch the sys_field value from prep_seq_num!=0 and primary_ind=1.
For both case only one instance/row must be possible.
So IF I have the following BILL table situation:

```
Tracking_ID  BSCO_CODE_ID  PREP_SEQ_NUM  ITEM_CAT_CODE_ID PRIMARY_IND SYS_FIELD
    1            PINGPONG        61             5               1        50
    2            PINGPONG        0              1               0        100
```

I should then fetch only the value 100 from sys_field where prep_seq_num=0
So in the first case I should run:

```
SELECT SYS_FIELD
      INTO v_start_of_invoice
      FROM BILL
     WHERE TRACKING_ID = v_previous_trackingID
       AND BSCO_CODE_ID = 'PINGPONG'
       AND CHRG_ACCT_ID = v_ACCT_ID
       AND PREP_SEQ_NUM = 0 -- maybe not needed here
       AND ITEM_CAT_CODE_ID=1
       AND PARTITION_KEY = v_prev_partition
       AND SUBPARTITION_KEY = v_prev_subpartition
       AND PRIMARY_IND=0;
```

In the second case, If by instance I have only the following (prep_seq_num=0 not existing)

```
Tracking_ID  BSCO_CODE_ID  PREP_SEQ_NUM  ITEM_CAT_CODE_ID PRIMARY_IND SYS_FIELD
    1            PINGPONG        61             5               1        50
```

I should take the value 50 from sys_field and therefore running the following query:

```
SELECT SYS_FIELD
      INTO v_start_of_invoice
      FROM BILL
     WHERE TRACKING_ID = v_previous_trackingID
       AND BILL_CODE_ID = 'PINGPONG'
       AND ITEM_CAT_CODE_ID in ('5' , '-100')
       AND PARTITION_KEY = v_prev_partition
       AND SUBPARTITION_KEY = v_prev_subpartition
       AND PRIMARY_IND=1;
```

I have many ideas but none really working I would like to get the most efficient/fast possibly in one query.
Thks

Comment: Can't you just rewrite the `WHERE` clause using an `OR` to handle both sets of logic?

Comment: thjere are quite few fields that are changes depending on that field value. IF prep_seq_num is eq  to 0 , some field is set with some value, if not = 0 , some field is set to difeerent value.

Comment: Since `prep_seq_num` will always be zero or "null or not zero", you can have two sets of criteria (in parentheses) separated by an `OR` clause, as shown in my answer.

Can you improve your question with some sample data & expected outputs?

Comment: Hi Brian, thks for you reply but I forgot to specify something which I just added in the summary descritpion: I can't select both options, if Both existing I should always get the row with prep_seq_num=0 (and not the other), otherwise if we do not have prep_seq_num=0 but let's say =60, then I should get this last one. Hope I made myself more clear !!!

Comment: Nobody is answering this silly question?????

Comment: Please review the numerous "how to ask a question" tutorials, and consider posting a SQL Fiddle with a minimum reproducible version of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is ranking: you prefer `prep_seq_num = 0 and primary_ind = 0` over `prep_seq_num <> 0 and primary_ind = 1`.

The typical way to do this is a limit clause. This is `FETCH FIRST ROWS` in standard SQL and availalble as of Oracle 12c. An alternative would be `ROW_NUMBER` which is also standard SQL and available in Oracle since 8i I think.

```
select sys_field
  into v_start_of_invoice
from bill
where tracking_id = v_previous_trackingid
  and bsco_code_id = 'PINGPONG'
  and partition_key = v_prev_partition
  and subpartition_key = v_prev_subpartition
  and 
  (
    (
      prep_seq_num = 0 and
      primary_ind = 0 and
      item_cat_code_id = 1 and
      chrg_acct_id = v_acct_id
    )
    or
    (
      prep_seq_num <> 0 and
      primary_ind = 1 and
      item_cat_code_id in (5, -100)
    )
  )
order by case when prep_seq_num = 0 then 1 else 2 end
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Another option is Oracle's `KEEP FIRST`:

```
select max(sys_field) keep (dense_rank first 
                            order by case when prep_seq_num = 0 then 1 else 2 end)
  into v_start_of_invoice
...
```

```
order by case when prep_seq_num = 0 then 1 else 2 end
fetch first 1 row only;
```

And here is the query with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
select sys_field
  into v_start_of_invoice
from
(
  select 
    sys_field, 
    row_number() over (order by case when prep_seq_num = 0 then 1 else 2 end) as rn
  from bill
  where tracking_id = v_previous_trackingid
    and bsco_code_id = 'PINGPONG'
    and partition_key = v_prev_partition
    and subpartition_key = v_prev_subpartition
    and 
    (
      (
        prep_seq_num = 0 and
        primary_ind = 0 and
        item_cat_code_id = 1 and
        chrg_acct_id = v_acct_id
      )
      or
      (
        prep_seq_num <> 0 and
        primary_ind = 1 and
        item_cat_code_id in (5, -100)
      )
    )
)
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: I guess this was what I was looking for, unfortunately I'm working with ORACLE 11g and do not have "fetch.." option to use. I'm searching how to use the row_number, I have some difficulty, if you can be so kind to help also here I would be grateful. Thks

Comment: I've added two alternative queries, one with `KEEP FIRST`, one with `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: YOU ARE THE MAN! IT WORKS